# Очистка выделенной памяти

Tags: c++

Привет, ruSO!

Я познакомился с С++ относительно недавно, но до познания дзена мне далековато. С ноября месяца к "плюсам" не притрагивался вообще. На днях решил вернуться к заброшенному пет-проекту, который начинал писать ещё во время изучения языка, заодно вспомнить "плюсы" и продолжить своё изучение. В проекте возникла проблемка с выделением памяти под данные и её последующей очисткой. На момент написания проекта я не смог разобраться с этой проблемой, а из-за нехватки времени забросил его вовсе.

Вчера просидел в дебагере пару часиков, переписал 80% кода того класса, где возникала ошибка (архитектура класса была совершенно кривая) и избавился от ошибок выделения и очистки памяти.
Приложение, наконец, выполняется безо всяких ошибок. Напоследок решил проверить корректность очистки памяти. Снова запускаю дебаг и внимательно слежу за данными, которые удаляю. Что странно, `delete myData` происходит, но данные остаются. Я подумал, что за пол-года успел забыть азы C++ и то, как работают указатели. Для проверки написал по-быстрому простенький пример:

```
uint* a = new uint;
*a = 5;

cout<<"Before delete:\t\t"<<*a<<" on address: "<<a<<endl;
delete a;
cout<<"After delete:\t\t"<<*a<<" on address: "<<a<<endl;
*a = 7;
cout<<"After delete & set:\t"<<*a<<" on address: "<<a<<endl;
```

Посмотрев на результаты выполнения кода я выпал в осадок:

```
Before delete:      5 on address: 0x7fe994c02700
After delete:       5 on address: 0x7fe994c02700
After delete & set: 7 on address: 0x7fe994c02700

Process finished with exit code 0
```

По всей видимости, я не дурак, азы помню, и такая проблема даже в простых примерах, а не только в моём коде. Но и это ещё не всё! Теперь дописываем две строки после третьего `cout`:

```
delete a;
cout<<"After second delete: "<<*a<<" on address: "<<a<<endl;
```

Запускаем дебаггер, смотрим результат и тихо сползаем под стол:

```
Before delete:      5 on address: 0x7f8193500000
After delete:       5 on address: 0x7f8193500000
After delete & set: 7 on address: 0x7f8193500000
my_test_prog(1774,0x7fffafdc8340) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f8193500000: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Signal: SIGABRT (signal SIGABRT)
Terminated due to signal 6

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Нет, я конечно понимаю, что невозможно удалить то, что уже удалено. Но ребят, к указателю спокойно можно обращаться после первой очистки памяти (при второй попытке приложение завершается аварийно, что неудивительно), получать адрес ячейки памяти, извлекать из него значение, записывать новое и т.д. Конечно, у меня в коде нет такой глупости, как двойное удаление выделенной памяти, эту строчку я дописал лишь для проверки, мол если ячейка памяти остаётся выделенной, значит её можно удалить. Но нет. Указатель сохраняется, значение сохраняется, а удалить нельзя!

Я поставил брэкпоинты на каждую строчку и следил за указателем `a`. После первого  вызова `delete` его адрес не менялся, значение не пропадало и, как видно выше, с ним спокойно можно было работать. Ну а второй `delete` попросту не сработал. На момент завершения программы указатель `a` всё ещё указывал на ячейку памяти с адресом `0x7f8193500000`, даже после попытки второго `delete`.

Меня всё ещё посещает мысль что я нуб и чего-то не понимаю, но по логике вещей, при очистке памяти ячейка должна полностью затираться. Как так-то? Если я правильно помню, то при обращении к ячейке памяти, которая была очищена, должна вылетать то ли ошибка на этапе выполнения (с аварийным завершением программы, а у меня так только при вызове второго `delete`), то ли "абракадабра" вместо значения, которое было записано в эту ячейку памяти. А у меня ничего этого не происходит, поэтому и обращаюсь к вам за помощью и советом.

Заранее благодарю за помощь.
С уважением, Юрий.

Рабочее окружение:

```
IDE: CLion, C++17
OS:  macOS High Sierra (v10.13.3)
```

P.S.: если в вопросе много "воды", искренне прошу прощения. Мне всегда было сложно кратко излагать мысли "по существу", да и к тому же на ruSO я не заходил уже очень давно, и хватку немного потерял. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор `delete` не меняет значения переданного указателя, но делает указатель невалидным. А вот программист несет ответственность за то, что в программе не будет разыменований невалидных указателей. Любая попытка сделать так приводит к неопределённому поведению.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Но что происходит с самой памятью? Она вообще очищается или нет? На приведённых примерах память всё ещё содержит записанное в неё значение. Если она не будет очищаться (освобождаться), при больших объёмах информации разве не будет переполнения ОЗУ? Меня волнует даже не то, что через невалидный указатель можно ещё обращаться к памяти, а то что память не очищается!

Comment: @intro94 С точки зрения встроенного аллокатора память освобождается. Но ее содержимое может и не изменяться, или изменяться случайным образом (если в другом потоке выделится этот же блок). Виртуальная память процесса может оставаться в нем и переиспользоваться (что обычно и происходит) или отдаваться обратно системе. То, что напечаталось `After delete: 5 on address: 0x7fe994c02700` ничего не говорит о том, освобождена память или нет.

Comment: Если я правильно понял ваши объяснения, то при выделении памяти (например через `new`) выделенная память блокируется данным процессом, а при использовании оператора `delete` указатель становится невалидным, а выделенная память освобождается процессом, хоть может и не очищаться её содержимое сразу, и доступна для выделения другими процессами? И в следствии этого, переполнения ОЗУ не будет?

Comment: @intro94 Реально память выделяется операционной системой. Но в с++ используется аллокатор памяти поверх системного, которой пытается минимизировать количество системных вызовов и обычно переиспользует память. "Указатель становится невалидным" подразумевает, что его разыменование является неопределенном поведением, ничего больше. А память, на которую он раньше указывал, могла быть переиспользована, а могла и не быть, могла остаться в процессе, а могла и не остаться, значение которое там было могло измениться, а могло и неизмениться.

Comment: Хм... Немного понял. Спасибо за разъяснения, теперь я спокоен. Значит можно с чистой совестью считать что утечки памяти нет и ошибки в коде исправлены. :) Надеюсь, в будущем у меня выстрелов в ногу будет чуть меньше, чем было вчера. xD